# How to remove Provisioning profile in xCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5, provisioning-profile

I have to make an **ipa** by **Ad-Hoc Distribution** but when I have to choose the Provisioning Profile, I have 2 same of them so how I can delete one? I check in my certificate and I have just 1 of that in developer apple panel. I have instal this provisioning profile many time because time by time I've had New device (I've added the provisioning more then 2 time) someone can help me?

this is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this in XCode 5 is using an [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). It lets you manually delete duplicates of provisioning profiles with ease and speed.

[image]

I keep Xcode closed when I do this just in case. Good luck!

Comment: Is the fist time that I like to lose point in stack overflow!! Thanks man!

Comment: I can give you the bounty in 23h so you have to wait ok?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano Sure, friend! Glad I was of help!

Comment: Note when going to Apple to download you may see "Note: iPhone Configuration Utility can install apps on OS X Mountain Lion and earlier. For OS X Mavericks, please use Apple Configurator." - Apple Configurator is not useful for managing the provisioning profiles, so still go ahead and download iPhone Configuration Utility.

Comment: Hello, Any update after Apple have dropped "iPhone Configuration Utility" and removed it from downloads ? Which app do you use to manage Xcode provisionings on 10.11 ? (I am still using iPhone configuration utility, but think that it should be another way now)

Comment: Still using the good old iPhone configuration utility until it works. And unfortunately I see no reason for Apple to make it anymore convenient in Xcode 8, but let's wait and see.